# What do the dotted lines on the map mean?

Tags: vignettes

In the iOS game Vignettes, there is a map screen which shows the paths you can use to travel between objects. Most paths are shown as solid lines, but a few paths use a dotted line instead.

What do the dotted lines mean on the map screen in Vignettes?

[image]